# The probability that the minimum number is unique

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I draw $n$ integers $X$ from $[1, n]$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that $\min\left(X\right)$ is unique, i.e. that there is only one number in $X$ that is $\min\left(X\right)$?

I tried to find a closed form solution for this, but I have not been successful.

I've tried to estimate the number both with sampling and also exactly, and it seems like it converges towards something like $< 0.59$, but I have no idea what this number is.

More generally, I would like to find the probability that the minimum is unique if I draw $n$ integers from $[1, r]$ for some integers $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \leq r$.

(Source: I want to estimate the success rate of an algorithm suggested as a solution to a question on [cs.sx](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155691)).

Answer (score 10):

Say you pick $1$ as the minimum. You are then free to choose the other $n-1$ numbers. This gives you $(n-1)^{n-1}$ ways of choosing them. Next is $2$. You have $n-2$ numbers to pick from now, but you still have to pick $n-1$ of them so $(n-2)^{n-1}$ ways of doing that, etc.

This results in

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n k^{n-1}$$

The extra factor $n$ is to account for the fact that the minimum can be picked at any moment in your selection process.

On the other hand, the total amount of combinations with no restrictions is $n^n$.

Thus, the probability is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{n-1}$$

You can apply the same reasoning to the other case to yield $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} \frac{n}{r}\left(\frac{k}{r}\right)^{n-1}$.

Computing up to $n=100$, I got $0.5812207$. And for $n=1000$, $0.5819012$.

[According to OEIS](https://oeis.org/A031971), this should be equal to $1/(e-1)$.

Comment: The $1/(e-1)$ result follows from the approximation $$\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^{n} \approx e^{-k},$$ so $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (k/n)^{n-1}\approx \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (e^{-k})^{(n-1)/n}$ is approximately a geometric series.

Comment: Perhaps worth saying $1/(e-1) \approx 0.5819767$

Comment: Also perhaps worth saying for large $n$ and $r$ you have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{r-1} \frac{n}{r}\left(\frac{k}{r}\right)^{n-1} \approx \frac{n}{r\left(\exp(n/r) -1\right)}$